# Maintaining in Khan's algorithm without hurting the running time(Asymptotically)

Tags: algorithm, analytics

Question(Data Structure):

Which representation should we use to calculate the in-degrees of a graph's vertices in O(|V|+|E|)? How should this be maintained in Khan's algorithm without hurting the running time (Asymptotically)? Prove your claims.

My attempt:
We should use a matrix representation to calculate the in-degrees because the adjacency-list only relates between the vertices and their outer-degrees while the matrix relates between both, and for that reason we should use matrix in order to calculate the in-degrees. I'm having hard time in the second part of the question.

Can you help please?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can easily store the *incoming* edges in adjacency lists, that's not the usual thing to do but that doesn't make it impossible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need an array.

You can fill it by iterating over all edges and increasing the in-degree for the end of each edge.

After that, you just need to decrease the in-degree of all neighbors of the node by one after you process a node.

An adjacency list would probably be the most convenient graph storage format for this problem.